# Replacing RVM with rbenv --mkmf error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

I was looking at replacing RVM with rbenv since I am using bundle to manage my gemfiles. rbenv,  I believe, is a lot lighter in managing my Ruby versions, so I uninstalled RVM and installed rbenv. I installed the bundler gem using

```
gem install bundler
```

because we need it everywhere. Then I opened a project and installed the required version Ruby using rbenv:

```
rbenv install 1.9.3-p194
rbenv local 1.9.3-p194
rbenv rehash
```

I entered `ruby -v` to make sure it was using the right version of Ruby, and it was, so I tried running bundle and it ran until it tried to install RedCloth and and then failed:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb --with-cflags=-w
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

It suggested that I install RedCoth before bundling, so I installed RedCloth:

```
gem install RedCloth
```

which succeeded. I then ran `ruby -v`, just to make sure it's still right, then tried running `bundle update` and the same error occured:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb --with-cflags=-w
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'

    Gem files will remain installed in /home/ruberto/.bundler/tmp/7551/gems/RedCloth-4.2.9 for inspection.
    Results logged to /home/ruberto/.bundler/tmp/7551/gems/RedCloth-4.2.9/ext/redcloth_scan/gem_make.out
    An error occurred while installing RedCloth (4.2.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
    Make sure that `gem install RedCloth -v '4.2.9'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I then tried installing a different version of Ruby but had no success there either.

Does anyone have ideas?

I subsequently tried doing the same thing in my other projects and it all seems to work just fine. I have one that uses 1.8.7 and it was as easy as setting the rbenv to the right version and then running bundle. I tried almost every combination of Ruby version and yet it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally overcame the problem.

I had installed a wrong version of Ruby 1.8.7-p370. I then ran bundle and that had some gems compiling the native extensions against Ruby 1.8.7 when the bundle was for a 1.9.3 package, so even if I was to switch over to the 1.9.3 version and try running bundle again it would bomb out.

To fix this, I simply removed all the gems and then installed the right version of Ruby and then re-ran bundle.

Comment: Rather than deleting and reinstalling the gems you could have used `gem pristine --all` which usually fixes problems with compile problems when updating Ruby versions. However, the way rbenv works it should have separate gem installs for each Ruby version installed, which should have been fixed by `bundle install` after installing a Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  It turned out that, even though I had the ~/.rbenv/shims directory at the front of my path, zsh was caching the location of bundle to /usr/local/bin/bundle.

The solution was simply running `rehash` at the shell (not `rbenv rehash`).  This flushed all the cached commands, including bundle, and all went well after that.